# Getting child values of 2nd or 3rd level has_many rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

This is how the model is structured.

```
User has_many :properties

Property has_many :rooms

Room has_many :bookings

Booking belongs_to :Room
```

The `booking` has a table attribute called `check_in`. So for getting all booked rooms for a user I can do below

create an array of rooms and loop through each
    rooms=[]

then for each room do below code

This will work for querying from room level

```
room.bookings.where("check_in == ?", Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day)
```

I can create few loops and get the result. But is there an efficient way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

Join tables while querying.

To get a set of rooms for particular user:

```
Room.joins(property: :user)
    .where(
      users:    { id: id_of_particular_user },
      bookings: { check_in: Time.zone.now.beginning_of_day }
    )
```

Comment: Andrey, do you have a blog sharing your knowledge/experience? you are almost in every rails/activerecord related posts and you always offer great solutions -))

Comment: @marmeladze thanks for this compliment - I am glad to know I help! But I am still noob, just a little less noob, than those, whose questions I answer :) But maybe someday I'll start a blog ;)

Comment: PG::UndefinedTable: ERROR: missing FROM-clause entry for table "bookings" LINE 1: ...erties"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 AND "bookings"... ^ : SELECT "rooms".* FROM "rooms" INNER JOIN "properties" ON "properties"."id" = "rooms"."property_id" INNER JOIN "users" ON "users"."id" = "properties"."user_id" WHERE "users"."id" = $1 AND "bookings"."check_in" = $2